# Passing param to a method in event listener without adding anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element on which I add 'input' event listener and assign a function to be executed during an input on an element. That function takes an argument, and I want to pass the same element to the function as an argument without adding an anonymous function to the event listener.

***My event listener:***

```
$(element).on('input', testMethod);
```

***My test method:***

```
function testMethod(paramElement)
{
// Do something
}
```

I wish to pass the element as the param element to testMethod during input on the element. Presently, when I input anything on the element, my paramElement is a jquery event and the element is within event.target. I wish my param element to be directly a javascript element and not a jquery event.

For this I tried adding an anonymous function in the event listener (as below), which works, but I am trying to figure out if I can pass the param without adding a anonymous function.

***Event listener with anonymous function:***

```
$(element).on('input', function(){testMethod(event.target);});
```

Is there a way to pass the param/element without using an additional function just to pass a param?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom value to the arguments passed to a function by using the `.bind()` method [[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function handleKeys(arg, e) {
  console.log(arg, e);
}

var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeys.bind(null, 'cats'))
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/duhaime/pen/eeBNxd)

From the MDN documentation:

> The **bind()** method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

**bind()** has he following function signature:

```
fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

In other words, we call `bind()` on a function (`fun`). The first argument passed to `.bind()` determines the value of the `this` keyword inside `fun`. Any additional arguments are passed to `fun`. Finally, any additional arguments that would be provided to `fun` are provided after these arguments from `.bind`.

So in the example above, we bind a null context to `handleKeys` then pass the string `cats`, and the `handleKeys()` function receives `cats` as its first argument followed by the `event` object that is automatically passed to event callbacks...

Comment: Cool. This worked! But why are we passing null and 'cats' as the 2nd argument even when in the method signature, arg is in the first place?

Comment: @tech_human, I updated my answer--does this help explain why `.bind()` works here? If so, please feel free to click the big green check box!